# Windows Server 2012 Terminal Server Degrading Performance on User Session

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012, windows-terminal-services

We have a terminal server environment with about 40 users which is experiencing a curious performance issue: when a given user logs in initially, everything functions properly, once a particular user starts to eat up more resources (upwards of 2GB/memory and 2%-5% of overall CPU usage), their applications seem to slow down considerably. If I have the user close everything, log off and log back in, performance on the applications is restored.

It's almost as if there's some kind of throttling on resources going on for each user session.

Has anyone experienced this phenonmenon? The server resources are adequate as at peak we're using 50%-70% CPU and about 75% of memory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Install the WPT 8.1 (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx) on the server, run WPRUI.exe, select CPU, DiskIO, FileIO, VAlloc, Resident Set) and capture a trace of 1 minute of the high resource usage. After you captured it, zip it (and the NGENPDB folder) to reduce the size, upload it to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here. I'll look at it, to see what happens on your server.

Comment: have you ever captured the trace of the Memory/CPU usage?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at WSRM
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997019.aspx

The default resource allocation is to divide up resources per number of connected users so, if you have 40 users each user will only be able to access one 40th of your memory and CPU.

Weighted_Remote_Sessions might be a more appropriate configuration for your environment.

Comment: We are on SQL 2012 R2, I believe this WSRM functionality was removed for R2.

Comment: You can WSRM it on 2012 R2 but it is a bit of a hack, see https://www.vioreliftode.com/index.php/windows-system-resource-manager-and-windows-server-2012-r2/ for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Also, could try a profile rebuild for said user.
See if the issue follows that user.

I'm sure you're more interested in the overall issue though than a quick fix.